# Receiving IDLE notifications using node-imap

Tags: node.js, imap, node-imap

I've successfully connected to a mailbox with `node-imap`:

```
const imap = new Imap({
    user: 'user@yandex.com',
    password: 'pwd',
    host: 'imap.yandex.com',
    port: 993,
    tls: true
});

imap.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Opening inbox');
    imap.openBox('INBOX', true, (error, mailbox) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        // ???

    });
});
```

How would I now get notified of new emails when they arrive? I've read up about IMAP and I should be using the IDLE command. But how would I achieve this with `node-imap`?

https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap

Comment: Looks like the `mail` event: https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap#connection-events

Comment: @ChrisWhite - yes it is! If you had any desire to pose that as an answer I'd love to give it the green tick.

Comment: How can i listen for this event, can you give a small example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After going through the documentation, it seems that the IMAP connection emits a `mail` event upon receiving new mail: https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap#connection-events, so listening for that event should be notification that there is new mail to be received or processed.

Comment: how can i listen for this event, can you give a small example?